# Does Firebase Analytics link data to user identity?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, app-store, firebase-analytics, privacy

I am trying to publish my React Native iOS app (which uses Firebase Analytics) on the App Store. The App Store requires me to specify what data is linked to the user.

The problem is: I cannot figure out whether Firebase Analytics links the data it collects to the user identity.

Specifically, I am unsure if Firebase Analytics links data from the following categories to the user identity: Contact Info, Identifiers, Diagnostics, Location, Usage Data, and Other Data. Can anyone advise?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found Google documentation explaining how to enable/disable privacy settings: [Privacy controls in Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9019185?hl=en&ref_topic=6317497#disable-web&zippy=%2Cin-this-article)

For **location data**, they state: "You have the option to enable/disable the collection of granular location-and-device data on a per-region basis. Analytics collects this data by default."

For **user level data acccess**, they state: "For Universal Analytics properties, you can pull event information for any given user identifier via the User Explorer report or the User Activity API. These features allow you to analyze and export event level data for a single user identifier. " -- I think this means that the data is in fact linked to user identities if you use Firebase Analytics.